# how to float all unordered lists to the left in a drop down div?

Tags: html, css

I want to float all unordered lists in my drop down menu (div) to the left.

this is the html:

```
<div class="dropdown"><li><h5><a href="#">« Back</a></h5></li>
                                <ul id="0">
                                        <li></li>
                                        <li></li>
                                        <li></li>
                                        <li></li>
                                        <li></li>
                                </ul>
                                <ul id="1">
                                        <li></li>
                                        <li></li>
                                        <li></li>
                                        <li></li>
                                        <li></li>
                                </ul>
                                <ul id="2">
                                        <li></li>
                                        <li></li>
                                        <li></li>
                                        <li></li>
                                        <li></li>
                                </ul>
                                <ul id="3">
                                        <li></li>
                                        <li></li>
                                        <li></li>
                                        <li></li>
                                        <li></li>
                                </ul>
                                <ul id="4">
                                        <li></li>
                                </ul>
                        </div>
```

this is the css:

```
.top-bar-section .dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    z-index: 99; }
    .top-bar-section .dropdown ul {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    }
    .top-bar-section .dropdown li {
      float: left;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
```

below is a picture of the current look and the desired look:
[image]

Comment: if you let each `ul` `float:left` it should work. not quite sure but it should do the job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why are you using `.top-bar-section` class here as your markup doesn't have any such class.

So I made simple markup and css for you. This might be helpful for you

Here is the CSS

```
.dropdown ul {
 list-style: none;
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align:top;
}
.dropdown ul li {
    display:block;
}
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vNQE9/2/)

Comment: sorry, it doesnt work, look at this image:
http://s29.postimg.org/bkmdjgrdj/Untitled.png

Comment: That means some other css rules creating the problem. In that case you need to share them as well with us..